# Visual Styles-related operation resulted in an error because no visual style is currently active. (System.Windows.Forms)

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016, always-encrypted

I have installed the latest version of the [SQL Server Management Studio 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) in order to test the [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx) feature. It is opened from this menu here:

[image]

but always throw the following error:

[image]

and then the studio stops working.

Has anyone idea what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was addressed in SSMS 16.3 (August 2016) Release. Please, upgrade your SSMS to the latest version of SSMS, available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt588477.aspx, if you still observe this issue. Alternatively, make sure you are not using the Classic Windows theme or a high-contrast theme.